# I don't like to be addicted to anything Vs.I like to be addicted to nothing

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

What's the difference between these two sentences? Do they mean the same?

> I don't like to be addicted to anything.
>
> I like to be addicted to nothing.

Basically I want to say that I don't like to be addicted even to one thing. Which of the above means that?

Comment: I'm not sure if this help or not, but: "I don't like to be hit by any sticks" vs. "I like to be hit by no sticks". Which of these would carry the meaning you want to convey?

Comment: I wish I understand the differences between these two sentences, too. I have a quite similar question.

Comment: Your second version is syntactically valid, but it wouldn't normally be used. There's a clue in your final paragraph, where when you want to "restate" what you want to say, you've quite naturally chosen to express it using ***I don't like...*** That's to say, you're making a statement about what you ***don't*** want, rather than what you ***do*** want. And after all, that's how most of us usually think - ***I don't want to die***, as opposed to ***I do want to not die***.

Comment: ...or ***I [do] want to win the Lottery*** (people ***do*** want "good" things). You won't often hear ***I don't want not to win the Lottery***.

Comment: In this instance it seems clear but I don't think there is a general rule, for example "He owns nothing." is more emphatic than "He doesn't own anything."

Comment: "There will be no end" (=there will not be end"): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3gEkwhdXUE&list=PLKz7h3vabE4FZSeFh_hLHqkuuSkvHQhfW&index=12

Answer (score 1):

"I don't like to be addicted to anything" is the most idiomatic. Typically, an English speaker would **not** say "I like to be addicted to nothing". The reason is that you either like something, or you don't like something. For example, if you didn't like mushrooms, you wouldn't say "I like no mushrooms". Your example is about *not* liking addictions, so you need to negate the word "like". As an alternative, you could say "I like to be free from addiction", which negates the word "addiction" from the outset.

With short sentences containing just a single verb and subject, it doesn't matter so much how you negate them. For example, to negate the sentence "I did something", you could either say "I did nothing", or "I didn't do anything".

With your example, it just feels misleading to begin a sentence in a way that sounds like you *are* addicted to something, only to conclude with "nothing". You can't be addicted to "nothing" - one is either addicted or not addicted.

There are exceptions. For example, to negate "I will bake a cake" we would most likely say "I will **not** bake a cake". Saying "I will bake no cake" doesn't sound natural in most contexts. However, we sometimes use that method way to add emphasis to a statement, for example, I saw a news headline recently that said "there will be **no** second wave", which is more emphatic than saying "there won't be a second wave", but less likely to be said in everyday speech.